# How do I start a gui framebuffer (no X) application on startup instead of console login prompt?

Tags: debian, gui, startup, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

I have a python application that uses pygame to access the framebuffer directly without using X. I want to start this application on startup instead of showing the console login prompt. I haven't found any good resources which explains how I would do it.

Just the same way gdm is started instead of showing a console login prompt.

Bonus question: 
What would happen if said application crashed? Would the console login prompt be shown?

**Edit: I have been reading up on runlevels and startup. More specific question below**

Will it be enough to create a `/etc/init.d` script which starts my python program, update rc.d with `update-rc.d` and setting priority to 99 so that it runs last and setting it to run under runlevel 5 (Which is for gui applications I heard). Then changing the default runlevel 5 in `/etc/inittab`?

Or do I have to do something special since the program uses framebuffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to run directy on the inittab... try to edit the /etc/inittab and replace the

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

with

```
1:2345:respawn:/usr/bin/python /srv/game/game.py
```

If the game crashes, init will restart it again. The game probably needs to know that is should open tty1 (or any other at your choice)

if you need the console, the other terminals should be normal, so ctrl+alt+F2 should jump to a login console

If you want to try with the runlevel, you are on good track... you probably need to define a TTY (probably export TTY=/dev/tty1) so the app knows where it should connect (as inittab and rc script run without any TTY defined). As i don't know python nor framebuffer consoles, dont know how to do that in python and what else is needed (maybe a more framebuffed or python direct question on stackoverflow is needed)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's interesting, didn't know you could do that. It seems easier too! I will try this out later today and get back to you.